# How do I fill up an array within an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am getting a little confused. I have the following array of objects:

```
dataTest.rows = [{
        "rowHeader": "",
        "rowDesc": ["INFO1"],
        "rowVal": [
            ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
        ]
    }, {
        "rowHeader": "",
        "rowDesc": ["INFO2"],
        "rowVal": [
            ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]

        ]
    }];
```

How would I fill up the array within the array `rowval` with a loop if `rowVal`, say in object1, was empty?

I tried

```
for (i=0; i<9; i++){
  (dataTest.rows[0]).rowVal[0][i]=i;
}
```

Should I completely remove the label 'rowVal', and then add it to the object to rebuild it?

Comment: wasn't quite get the question here, all you need is replace all the item in `rowVal` with same value of index?

Comment: And whats the result of your loop?

Comment: You need to convert the number to a string in your loop - the example you gave contains strings and not numbers. Also "if rowVal, say in object1, was empty", you'd need to create an array first to modify.

Comment: Your question just doesn't make sense. What do you mean by 'was empty?' at the end? Do you mean if `rowVal` had no arrays?

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what you want the data to look like **after** the loop

Comment: I've pretty much already wrote the answer, I just need clarification on what precisely you want to add and to where.

Comment: the idea is ultimately to load data from a json file to the array rowVal.  and display the data into an embedded dynamic table (Tabella.js) but i first need to understand how to load simple data (number or string) in row Val in order to display them in teh table

Answer (score 1):

```js
var dataTest={};
dataTest.rows = [{
        "rowHeader": "",
        "rowDesc": ["INFO1"],
        "rowVal": [[]]
    }, {
        "rowHeader": "",
        "rowDesc": ["INFO2"],
        "rowVal": [[]]
    }];
for (var i=0; i<dataTest.rows.length; i++){
    // iteriates through the dataTest.rows array of objects
    console.log("Entered row %i",i);
    for (var j=1; j<=9; j++){
        // converts number to string
        dataTest.rows[i].rowVal[0][j]=j.toString();
       console.log(dataTest.rows[i].rowVal[0][j]);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Fixed "dataTest.rows[i].rowVal[0] is undefined."

Comment: dataTest.row[i].rowVal[0] is undefined?

Comment: @ApisMel I fixed that. It needs to have the sub-array included.

Comment: cool! thanks for helping.. this is working great.. now i can go to the next step.. get the data from a json file

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .forEach() Array method to loop through every item in array X and push it into array Y.

```
let dataTest= [{
    "rowHeader": "",
    "rowDesc": ["INFO1"],
    "rowVal": []
}, 

{
    "rowHeader": "",
    "rowDesc": ["INFO2"],
    "rowVal": [
        ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]

    ]
}];

dataTest[1].rowVal.forEach(number => {
                dataTest[0].rowVal.push(number)
                })
```

In this example, the forEach function runs through every item in the dataTest[1].rowVal and pushes everything inside into the array in dataTest[0].rowVal, which should achieve what you're asking.

Comment: what if both array are empty.

Comment: You can run a for loop before the forEach function, where i = 1 and the second argument is i < X, where X is the top end of the range.